# Put each value of an array in a new variable in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array composed of files of a folder.
When I use the following snippet :

```
foreach($myarray as $key => $value)
{
echo $value. "<br>";
}
```

I have the following output :

```
vendor/templates/File1.docx
vendor/templates/File2.docx
vendor/templates/File3.docx
```

My question is : how to make it to put each value of my array in a new variable ?  How to make it automatically if I have e.g 100 files in my folder ?
Actually I'd like to have (if my array is only composed of 3 items) :

```
$a = 'vendor/templates/File1.docx'   
$b = 'vendor/templates/File2.docx'   
$c = 'vendor/templates/File3.docx'
```

I guess I should use a loop but after many tests, I'm still getting stuck..
Have you any ideas ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You already have it stored in a variable; `$myarray`.

Comment: I'd like to store each item of my array (and not the whole array) in a new variable. Each item corresponding to a different variable

Comment: The problem you're going to run into is naming and accessing the new variables, you're going to have to use a loop so you might as well use the existing array. What's your thinking behind needing to do this?

Comment: Any specific purpose you are trying to achieve using this?

Comment: you may use [`extract`](http://php.net/extract) to do this;

Comment: My goal is to merge each file in a global docx file. If there's 3 files in my folder I'd like to merge the three of them. And the merging is based on the following code : $merge->merge( [
    'file1.docx',
    'file2.docx'
], "result.docx" );

Comment: @jeroen:*"extract() needs an associative array."*: It's wrong.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Oops, it seems you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
<?php

$myarray = ['vendor/templates/File1.docx', 'vendor/templates/File2.docx', 'vendor/templates/File3.docx'];

foreach($myarray as $key => $value)
{
    $varname = "var".$key;
    $$varname = $value;
}

echo $var0."\n";
echo $var1."\n";
echo $var2."\n";
```

->

```
vendor/templates/File1.docx
vendor/templates/File2.docx
vendor/templates/File3.docx
```

Comment: hi @hassan. I don't think it can work because the documentation states "This function treats keys as variable names and values as variable values.". Variables names cannot start with a number in PHP. If the array was `['one' => 'value', 'two' => 'value']` it would be the perfect solution

Comment: This is exactly what I need ! Thank you very much Gab for the help !!

Answer (score 0):

May be following function will work for your problem.

```
extract($array);
```

http://php.net/extract

Comment: It's indeed the way to go, except that you need to use the prefix parameter and the correct flag.